# Vujs and Vuetify Different Data Manipulation

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to manipulate data from different table (mariadb) in the same database, but idk how to make it good. It work with only single data but when there is more than 1 data it push it to right, and I want to make it vertically... Someone have a solution ? :-)

```
<v-simple-table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-left">
        <v-card-subtitle><strong>Congé</strong></v-card-subtitle></th>
      <th class="text-left">
        <v-card-subtitle><strong>Absence</strong></v-card-subtitle></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
      <td v-for="conge in conges" :key="conge.id">
        {{ conge.dateDebut }}  à  {{ conge.dateFin}}
      </td>
      <td v-for="absence in absences" :key="absence.id">
        {{ absence.dateDebut }}  à  {{ absence.dateFin }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</v-simple-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code :

```
<template>
  <v-simple-table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-left">
          <v-card-subtitle>
            <strong>Congé</strong>
          </v-card-subtitle>
        </th>
        <th class="text-left">
          <v-card-subtitle>
            <strong>Absence</strong>
          </v-card-subtitle>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(data, index) in mergedData" :key="index">
        <td>{{ data.conge.dateDebut }}  à  {{ data.conge.dateFin }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.absence.dateDebut }}  à  {{ data.absence.dateFin }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-simple-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mergedData: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    absences() {
      return [
        { id: 1, dateDebut: "2022-01-01", dateFin: "2022-01-02" },
        { id: 2, dateDebut: "2022-01-03", dateFin: "2022-01-04" }
      ];
    },
    conges() {
      return [
        { id: 1, dateDebut: "2022-02-01", dateFin: "2022-02-02" },
        { id: 2, dateDebut: "2022-02-03", dateFin: "2022-02-04" }
      ];
    }
  },
  created() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.conges.length; i++) {
      this.mergedData.push({
        conge: this.conges[i],
        absence: this.absences[i]
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: this code don't really work for me because I import api in method and from a database, idk why it print nothing

Comment: Since you didn't post that part of your code, this seems like a correct answer to your original question.